# Why is Mac OS X Lion Apache DocumentRoot /usr/htdocs?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, apache-http-server

I am baffled.

I don't see where `/usr/htdocs` is specified as the DocumentRoot for apache2 on Mac OS X Lion.

It is the default DocumentRoot on a new OSX Lion install.

Can someone point me to where this is specified?

I looked in the entire `/etc/apache2` directory and could not find that rule.

Comment: nothing in the `/etc/apache2/available-sites/*` configs?

Comment: The default OSX setup does not use the available-sites or enabled-sites structure.

Comment: It's not. A new OS X Lion installation uses `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, just like the major releases before Lion, which is also where the button *Open Computer Website Folder…* in *System Preferences » Sharing » Web Sharing* points to. Did you install a package manager like Homebrew, Fink, or MacPorts; XAMPP or a similar Apache solution? What is the output of `which httpd` and `ps aux | grep httpd` in Terminal?

Comment: I did not install any of those package managers. But thanks, I will look down that path. I do see the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` directive in the httpd.conf file. However, it is obviously being overwritten somewhere else. I tried following all the references to other .conf file, but no luck yet.

Comment: Why not `grep` for `/usr/htdocs` on your machine and see where it's overwritten? — (/cc @dan, you didn't get a reply for this)

Comment: When you write *new OSX Lion install*, this implies that you didn't restore e.g. your personal data from a Time Machine backup, right? (Thanks @slhck)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When "Web Sharing" is NOT enabled it takes `/usr/htdocs` as the root. When you enable "Web Sharing" it will take the config file at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. The directory will be the one specified near the following section on the file.

```
<IfDefine WEBSHARING_ON>
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

Also you con use your "Sites" directory at `/Users/USERNAME/Sites` accessing with `localhost/~USERNAME`.

Comment: Spot on.  Note also the line `ServerRoot "/usr"` - with Web Sharing OFF and no alternate DocumentRoot specified, it seems the Apache default is to look for `htdocs` within the defined Server Root.

Comment: Is that true that   some     <IfDefine WEBSERVICE >    should be commented since its a WEBSERVICE   ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable your Web Sharing first, Go to the system preferences -> Sharing then enable web sharing. [I wrote a post on it.](http://dimaspriyanto.com/2011/11/23/how-to-fix-document-root-error-apache-on-osx-lion/)

Comment: Could you add more detail? Your post contains more information than what you said here.

Comment: so he wrote a post, go and read it and congifigure your web sharing in lion ))) I did this too, earlier now I have folder "Sites" in my home dir and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

This Q helped me solve identical problem on SnowLeopard today. Beware: it was the `httpd.conf` in `/private/etc/apache2` **not in** `/etc/apache2` (which also exists) that got read and pointed to `/Library/WebServer/Documents` in my case.

I hope this helps (others too).

Comment: The entire /etc folder is a link to /private/etc so the two are one and the same.

Comment: @Fireandlight27 I don't think it was on SL, as I would'n write otherwise. I'm glad they are linked in your case; which OS version?